# intuitive question about the boundary of a set

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Consider $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ two convex, bounded domains in $R^n$ with $\Omega_1 \supset \overline{\Omega_2}$ suppose that $\operatorname{dist}(x, \partial \Omega_2) =\min_{y \in \partial \Omega_2} |x - y| = \lambda>0$ for all $x \in \partial \Omega_1$. Can I say anything about the regularity of $\partial \Omega_1$? I am asking this for curiosity. It seems that the regularity will be $C^1$. Someone could point me a reference please?

Comment: @orangeskid The way I read this, $\lambda$ does not depend on $x$, hence $\Omega_1$ could be something like $\bigcup_{x\in\Omega_2}B(x,\lambda)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Oh, wait a moment, I see, that $\lambda$ does not change with $x$.. Let me erase my previous comment. Thanks!

Comment: $\Omega_1$ looks like a $\lambda$-neighborhood of $\Omega_2$.

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen: you re right. Lambda doesnt depend on x

Comment: Looking at a point $x\in \partial\Omega_2$, the nearby boundary is confined between a (in fact: the) tangent at $x$ and the $\lambda$-circle around $y$ with $|x-y|=\lambda$. This enforces $C^1$ regularity at $x$.

Comment: A good reference for this kind of thing is Rolf Schneider's *Convex Bodies: The Brunn-Minkowski Theory* (Cambridge UP, 1993).

Comment: The optimal regularity should be $C^{1,1}$, that is, the normal vector is a Lipschitz function of boundary point. But I don't have a reference (I did look in Schneider's book, unsuccessfully).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Care Bear .

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen : Do you know where I can find a proof of your affirmation?I am not good with geometry...